# program type already present: javax.inject.Named + transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED

Tags: java, android

I'm using gradle version 4.4 and android plugin version 3.1.4 while building i am getting error as follows:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: javax.inject.Named","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
:tractorapp:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':tractorapp:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
```

Comment: Add app gradle file code also to review the dependencies you have used in your project

Comment: delete build folder, sync project with gradle then clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, delete `.gradle` and `.idea` folders after closing this project in Android Studio and then re open the project and then follow this:

Enable multiDex in your app `build.gradle` file. This should help you solve this. Also share the `build.gradle` file here so that we can figure out what is causing the issue properly.

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: If this doesnt work then share me the gradle file here. Might be dagger / javax issues for you , need to tweak around the gradle file to resolve it looks like  

@Srihari